# load image/splash screen does not appear on ipad

Tags: ipad, xcode4, screen, splash-screen

I have a 1024x768 default load image for the iPad that displays in Xcode, but doesn't display on the iPad.  There is a warning icon in Xcode4, but there is no explanation provided.  What is wrong?

Comment: How are you naming your default load image? At the bare minimum, you need to have a file called 'Default.png' (mind the capitalized D) in your project. Are you doing that?

Comment: @Julio Xcode4 automatically names the file Default-Landscape~ipad.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't trust Xcode 4 to name your files correctly. Here's how you should be naming the default images on iPad:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1588/_index.html

- Default-PortraitUpsideDown.png - upside-down portrait version.
- Default-LandscapeLeft.png - left-oriented landscape version.
- Default-LandscapeRight.png - right-oriented landscape version.
- Default-Portrait.png - generic portrait version.
- Default-Landscape.png - generic landscape version
- Default.png - default portrait launch. Its usage is strongly discouraged, use more
  specific launch images instead.

Comment: I renamed to Default-Landscape.png, it's part of the project, and doesn't show up on the iPad.  It does show in the simulator.

Comment: The problem was that the file was a jpg saved with a png extension.  The file is saved now under Default-Landscape~ipad.png and works well.  Thanks for your help.